Conversion to SwiftData - BackingData?
I wanted to update my app from CoreData to SwiftData. Experiencing a bit before touching the actual app, see how it works and things like that.
I created the SwiftData from my app using the Create SwiftData Code menu, and it generated this:
@Model public class MeasureData {
    var age: Int32? = 0
    var bellyValue1: Int32? = 0
    var bellyValue2: Int32? = 0
    var bellyValue3: Int32? = 0
    var bmi: Double? = 0.0
    var bmiUUID: String?
    var bodyFat: Double? = 0
    var bodyFatUUID: String?
    var chestValue1: Int32? = 0
    var chestValue2: Int32? = 0
    var chestValue3: Int32? = 0
    var comments: String?
    var fatBodyMass: Double? = 0.0
    var gripL: Double? = 0.0
    var gripR: Double? = 0.0
    var height: Double? = 0.0
    var leanBodyMass: Double? = 0.0
    var leanBodyMassUUID: String?
    var measureDate: Date?
    var savedToHealth: Bool?
    var thighValue1: Int32? = 0
    var thighValue2: Int32? = 0
    var thighValue3: Int32? = 0
    var userGenerated: Bool?
    var waist: Double? = 0.0
    var waistUUID: String?
    var weight: Double? = 0.0
    public init() {

    }
    
}

With this, my code to add an item works fine:
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = MeasureData(comments: "new comment")
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

This code is the default one when you create a new Swiftui with SwiftData project, just updated Item model to MeasureData model, since that is what I use instead.
However, I've read the recommendation to perform the init() differently, which I did this way:
@Model class MeasureData {
    var age: Int32? = 0
    var bellyValue1: Int32? = 0
    var bellyValue2: Int32? = 0
    var bellyValue3: Int32? = 0
    var bmi: Double? = 0.0
    var bmiUUID: String?
    var bodyFat: Double? = 0
    var bodyFatUUID: String?
    var chestValue1: Int32? = 0
    var chestValue2: Int32? = 0
    var chestValue3: Int32? = 0
    var comments: String?
    var fatBodyMass: Double? = 0.0
    var gripL: Double? = 0.0
    var gripR: Double? = 0.0
    var height: Double? = 0.0
    var leanBodyMass: Double? = 0.0
    var leanBodyMassUUID: String?
    var measureDate: Date?
    var savedToHealth: Bool?
    var thighValue1: Int32? = 0
    var thighValue2: Int32? = 0
    var thighValue3: Int32? = 0
    var userGenerated: Bool?
    var waist: Double? = 0.0
    var waistUUID: String?
    var weight: Double? = 0.0
    
    init(
        age: Int32?,
        bellyValue1: Int32?,
        bellyValue2: Int32?,
        bellyValue3: Int32?,
        bmi: Double?,
        bmiUUID: String?,
        bodyFat: Double?,
        bodyFatUUID: String?,
        chestValue1: Int32?,
        chestValue2: Int32?,
        chestValue3: Int32?,
        comments: String?,
        fatBodyMass: Double?,
        gripL: Double?,
        gripR: Double?,
        height: Double?,
        leanBodyMass: Double?,
        leanBodyMassUUID: String?,
        measureDate: Date?,
        savedToHealth: Bool?,
        thighValue1: Int32?,
        thighValue2: Int32?,
        thighValue3: Int32?,
        userGenerated: Bool?,
        waist: Double?,
        waistUUID: String?,
        weight: Double?) {
            
        self.age = age
        self.bellyValue1 = bellyValue1
        self.bellyValue2 = bellyValue2
        self.bellyValue3 = bellyValue3
        self.bmi = bmi
        self.bmiUUID = bmiUUID
        self.bodyFat = bodyFat
        self.bodyFatUUID = bodyFatUUID
        self.chestValue1 = chestValue1
        self.chestValue2 = chestValue2
        self.chestValue3 = chestValue3
        self.comments = comments
        self.fatBodyMass = fatBodyMass
        self.gripL = gripL
        self.gripR = gripR
        self.height = height
        self.leanBodyMass = leanBodyMass
        self.leanBodyMassUUID = leanBodyMassUUID
        self.measureDate = measureDate
        self.savedToHealth = savedToHealth
        self.thighValue1 = thighValue1
        self.thighValue2 = thighValue2
        self.thighValue3 = thighValue3
        self.userGenerated = userGenerated
        self.waist = waist
        self.waistUUID = waistUUID
        self.weight = weight
    }
}

Now the same code tells me this:

Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'BackingData'

On that line:
            let newItem = MeasureData(comments: "new comment")

The first "(" is underlined and red, as well as the first quotation mark.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, if anyone has an idea?
If no one knows, can someone at least review the updated model and see if there is something not correct in it?
Thank you
Tried to find what I did wrong but I've found nothing yet, hence asking the community :)

Your memberwise initialiser takes values for reach property, and while those values are optional, you have not specified default values (ie =nil), which means you cannot simply omit those parameters from the initialisation. when you call MeasureData(comments:) Swift isn't matching against your memberwise initialiser because there are insufficient arguments. It is attempting to invoke some other initialiser that accepts BackingData

Hi @Paulw11. Thank you for your answer. While I understand what you say, I'm not sure which part of my model I'm supposed to amend to account for the default value. Could you clarify this?

Your init needs to be something like init(age:Int32?=nil, bellyValue1:Int32?=nil....). Providing default values allows the arguments to the initialiser to be omitted.

@Paulw11: added it for "comments" only, didn't work, added it for all of them and now it works without error message! Thank you very much :)

I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add RESOLVED or SOLVED to the title, or to edit the solution into the question. If you've found a way to solve the problem and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See Can I answer my own question? for details. If someone else provided an answer that gave you a solution, acknowledge that by accepting their answer and upvoting it. For more information, see the [help] pages.

Hi @KenWhite: how do I accept and upvote a comment? I only see a option to flag the comment, nothing else. I cannot even thank him for the answer :(

You don't. As I said, If someone else provided an answer.  You've already thanked them in a comment
